# How to take a transpose for each matrix in a batch in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

Say I have a 4 batch of 5x3 matrixes. So the dimensions of these tensor are 4x5x3. How do I take the transpose of each matrix within each batch. So converting it to 4x3x5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will drop some benchmarks here for the sake of performance. Using the same tensor proposed in the OP's answer.

```
In[2]: import torch
In[3]: x = torch.randn(2, 3, 5)
In[4]: x.size()
Out[4]: torch.Size([2, 3, 5])
In[5]: %timeit x.permute(1, 0, 2)
1.03 µs ± 41.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In[6]: %timeit torch.transpose(x, 0, 1)
892 ns ± 9.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In[7]: torch.transpose(x, 0, 1).equal(x.permute(1, 0, 2))
Out[7]: True
```

It is clear that [`torch.transpose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.transpose) is faster, so It is advised to use it when possible.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the OP wanted to transpose dimensions 1 and 2. Thus, the `torch.transpose` call in that case will be `torch.transpose(x, 1, 2)`

Answer (score 3):

[`torch.transpose(input, dim0, dim1)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=torch%20transpose#torch.transpose)  will swap two dimensions.

```
>>> x = torch.randn(2, 3)
>>> x
tensor([[ 1.0028, -0.9893,  0.5809],
        [-0.1669,  0.7299,  0.4942]])
>>> torch.transpose(x, 0, 1)
tensor([[ 1.0028, -0.1669],
        [-0.9893,  0.7299],
        [ 0.5809,  0.4942]])
```

If more dimensions are desired to be swapped, use [`torch.Tensor.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=torch%20permute#torch.Tensor.permute)

```
>>> x = torch.randn(2, 3, 5)
>>> x.size()
torch.Size([2, 3, 5])
>>> x.permute(2, 0, 1).size()
torch.Size([5, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

As a warning, do:

```
torch.transpose(x, 1, 2)
```

if you have a tensor of size `[B, T, D]`. Doing `.t()` for example, only works for matrices. This is useful for doing a matrix multiple between two tensors of matrices with:

```
att = torch.transopose(x, 1, 2) @ x
```

or if you want the variable length sequences to face each other and cancel that dimension out.